# How to add new data from ebay to database in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using `python ebay-sdk` library for connection to ebay api.

I want to get some cases from ebay api and save it to the database.

I have one app and models like this:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    # case is not necessarily a listing (often O2M)
    STATUS = Choices('new', 'cancelled', 'active', 'taken_down', 'archived')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    when_created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make)
    status = StatusField(default=STATUS.new)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    listing_owner = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    # for now currency as char is ok.
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='USD')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    when_listing_started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    when_listing_ends = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_days = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(CaseQueryset)()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def days_valid(self):
        created = self.when_created.replace(tzinfo=None)
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=None)
        datetime.timedelta(6, 1)
        return (now - created).days

    def handle_sent_report(self):
        self._set_active_state()

    def handle_cancel(self):
        self._set_cancelled_state()

    def _set_active_state(self):
        if self.status != Case.STATUS.new:
            raise InvalidCaseStatus
        self.status = Case.STATUS.active
        self.save()

    def _set_cancelled_state(self):
        if self.status not in (Case.STATUS.new, Case.STATUS.active):
            raise InvalidCaseStatus
        self.status = Case.STATUS.cancelled
        self.save()
```

And I created other app `ebay-finder` and `ebay_find.py` to find cars in eBay:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding

from django.db import models

from cases.models import Case
from trademarks.models import Make


def ebay_find():
    pass

api = Finding(domain='svcs.sandbox.ebay.com', appid="MY_EBAY_APP_ID", config_file=None)
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'Cadillac'})
items = response.dict()
items_list = items['searchResult'].get('item')

ebay_cases = []

for item in items_list:
    new_case = Case.objects.create(
        name=item['title'],
        platform="Ebay",
        listing_id=car["model"],
        url=item['viewItemURL'],
        price=item['sellingStatus']['currentPrice']['value'],
        currency=item['sellingStatus']['currentPrice']['_currencyId']
    )
    new_case.save()
```

I'm confused how to add this data from items_list to my database like in `Case`. I must take all the same fields like in `Case`? Can I have some fields default on create object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want your data to be saved with the least hassle, then yes, use the same field-names.

You have an example of a model field with a default in your own code:

```
currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='USD')
```

You could also override your model's save() method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Case, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.when_listing_started:
        self.when_listing_started = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Case, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ok, but when I have in Case class 'make' which is ForeignKey, and I have use it the same in my ebay_finder script, it takes this field value or I have to add this one again in script?

Comment: Not sure I understood entirely, but to assign a make you would need to either: `self.make = Make.objects.filter(pk=1).first()` or `self.make_id = 1`